# difference between two date and display it in input by using php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

I have three input in html. two of them are start date and end date and the third one is to find the difference between them and display the result .

here is the inputs:

```
<p><span>Start date:</span> <input type="date" required min="2012-01-01" name="start_d" id="start_d" ><span>* Format: YYYY-MM-DD</span><br></p>
<p><span>End date:</span> <input type="date" required min="2012-01-01" name="end_d" id="end_d" ><span>* Format: YYYY-MM-DD</span><br></p>
<p><span>Duration :</span><input type="text" required name="duration" id=duration" readonly="readonly"><br></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2011-02-01");
$date2 = new DateTime("2012-01-01");
$duration = $date1->diff($date2);
var_dump($duration);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
date('Y-m-d', (strtotime($str_start_date) + round((strtotime($str_end_date) - strtotime($str_start_date)) / 2))';
```

**EDIT:**

Missunderstood your question. Though you wanted the date between these? You want the difference in seconds?

```
round((strtotime($str_end_date) - strtotime($str_start_date)) / 2)
```

Comment: where should i use this? I mean I want to view the result in he 3rd input how can i do this?

Comment: You wish to generate this when the other 2 values are selected? That'd be a javascript solution, not a php as you tagged it.

Comment: so it will work with javascript. how?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how exactly you want this.

Comment: basically, start date input then end date input and the third input to display the difference between them.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php and [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)